# iOS instance variable declaration

Tags: ios, objective-c, declaration, ivar

I would like to know what's the difference between declaring my instance variables like this:

```
// inside the implementation file (.m)

 @interface MyCustomObject()
 {
    id _myIvar;
 }

 @end

 @implementation MyCustomObject
 ...
 @end
```

And like this:

```
// inside the implementation file (.m)

 @implementation MyCustomObject{
    id _myIvar;
 }
 ...
 @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the point of view of the **USE**, there is **not difference**.

From the point of view of the declaration, the first one is a `Category`:

```
@interface MyCustomObject()
{

}
```

so **if you have a variable with the same name in the header file**, **your implementation file will see this one**, but **other classes whose import that header file, will see the other one**.

This mechanism can be really useful to assign **different attributes or properties to the same var**, **but differencing the exposed var, from the private internal var**.